# Why does my function execute before my promise callback?

Tags: javascript, promise

Why does a function called after my promise execute before the promise's callback?

I read this in MDN, but didn't understand it

> "Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current
>   run of the JavaScript event loop."

I thought it meant that if I have any other statements after `resolve()` or `reject()` they will get executed before the callback is invoked. Though, that seems to be an incomplete understanding.

```
function myFunction() {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {

    const err = false;

    if(err) {
      reject("Something went wrong!!!");
    }
    else {
      resolve("All good");
    }
  });
}

myFunction().then(doSuccess).catch(doError);
doOther();

function doError(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

function doSuccess() {
  console.log('Success');
}

function doOther() {
  console.log("My Other Function");
}
```

**Output:**

My Other Function

Success

Comment: It means exactly what you've observed; `doOther` is executed in the current run, so the callbacks will *never* get called before it.

Comment: Your question applies to promise `.then()` callbacks, not to callbacks in general.  There are many callbacks that are called synchronously such as what you pass to `array.filter()`.

Comment: This article helped me understand: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-javascript/#:~:text=JavaScript%20is%20a%20single%2Dthreaded,associate%20it%20with%20synchronous%20operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specification, a promise `.then()` or `.catch()` callback is never called synchronously, but is called on a future tick of the event loop.  That means that the rest of your synchronous code always runs before any `.then()` handler is called.

So, thus your `doOther()` function runs before either `doSuccess()` or `doError()` are called.

Promises are designed this way so that a promise `.then()` handler will be called with consistent timing whether the promise is resolved immediately or resolved some time in the future.  If synchronous `.then()` handlers were allowed, then calling code would either have to know when it might get called synchronously or you'd be susceptible to weird timing bugs.

In the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) which the promises in the ES6 specification were based on, it defines a `.then() handler like this:

```
promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
```

and then has this to say about it:

> 2.2.4. onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code. [3.1].

And, then it defines platform code like this:

> Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as setTimeout or setImmediate, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as MutationObserver or process.nextTick. Since the promise implementation is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.

Basically what this means is that `.then()` handlers are called by inserting a task in the event loop that will not execute until the currently running Javascript finishes and returns control back to the interpreter (where it can retrieve the next event).  So, thus any synchronous Javascript code you have after the `.then()` handler is installed will always run before the `.then()` handler is called.

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed answer.

Comment: You mention _If synchronous .then() handlers were allowed, then calling code would either have to know when it might get called synchronously or you'd be susceptible to weird timing bugs._ Could you give one or two examples of those timing bugs?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar confusions about what it means by executing after the current loop. I was going through [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#guarantees) on Promises, which says the following:

> Callbacks added with then() will never be invoked before the completion of the current run of the JavaScript event loop.

This website http://latentflip.com/loupe/ video expains it pretty well, basically api's like `setTimeout` execute after the inbuilt js functions. But, the problem with callbacks is, if it doesn't use those apis then it might execute before the finish of current run of the event loop. Following examples show the difference:

**Old school callbacks**

```js
var foo = function(then1) {
  console.log("initial");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 1000000000) {
    i++;
  }
  then1();
}

function then11() {
  console.log("res");
}
foo(then11);
console.log("end"); // unlike Promises, end is printed last
```

**New Promise**

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
  console.log("Initial");
  //while loop to 10000
  var i = 0;
  while(i<1000000000) { //long async task without ext apis
    i++;
  }  
  resolve("res");
});

promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
});

console.log("end"); // end is printed before res!!!
```